# How to use usestate inside a map -react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Getting below error while trying to update a preloaded value onchange using useState inside map
*React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks*

I'm trying to display a value from data array on a custom date field and on change update it to new selected date. When I'm trying to use a useState hook inside a map, I'm getting the below error. I'm a beginner in  react and trying to figure out how to fix. Thanks in advance.

```
const funName = () => {
return (
<>
.........
{data.map((eachData, index) => {
              const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState("new Date(eachData.eDate)");
              return (
                    <CustomComponent
key={index}
                      selected={endDate}
                      onChange={(date) => setEndDate(date)}
                    />
              );
            })}
</>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `useState` in `map` you need to declare it in top (before return)

```
const funName = () => {
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState();
    return (
        <>
            .........
            {data.map((eachData, index) => {
                return (
                    <CustomComponent
                        key={index}
                        selected={endDate}
                        onChange={setEndDate}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: But I want to display data loaded from the map and change that value on onChange.

Comment: If you want to have `date` for each `CustomComponent` you can declare it in `CustomComponent`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it, use useState inside your Custom component, just forward "eachData" to that component and implement logic inside with useState.